# Is not supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'. Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant

Tags: spring, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying connect a session in microsoft Web to read emails use java Spring boot but when trying connect get that error:

Application 'id-cliente'(JavaMail) is not configured as a multi-tenant application. Usage of the /common endpoint is not supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'. Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant.

Application 'id-cliente'(JavaMail) is not configured

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

> Application is not configured as a multi-tenant application. Usage of the /common endpoint is not supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'. Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant.

**The error usually occurs** if you are trying to use common endpoint to connect to the session.

Based on your requirement configure the application as **`Single-Tenant`** or **`Multi-Tenant`**.

If you want your application to be as a **Single-Tenant**, then make use of Tenant-Specific endpoint to authorize the request and configure the Azure AD Application like below:

[image]

And the Enpoints like below:

Authorize Enpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

Token Endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

When I tried to authorize the request, I am able to successfully connect:

[image]

If you want your application to configured as **Multi-Tenant**, the configure the Application like below:

[image]

And the Endpoints are like below:

Authorize Endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

Token Endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

When I tried to authorize the request, I am able to successfully connect:

[image]

Try configuring the changes accordingly as **`Single-Tenant`** and **`Multi-Tenant`** based on requirement.

Comment: Your answer was very useful for solving the problem. I currently have another problem. I am trying to log in but I get a 401 error and in the console: Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized, 401 Unauthorized: [{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.", "innerError":{"date":"2022-12-12T11:15:16","request-id":"XXXXXXXXX","client-request-id":"XXXXXXXXX"}}}]

Comment: You can now fix the mentioned error by changing the property:

security.oauth2.client.scope=https://outlook.office.com/.default

security.oauth2.client.scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default