Nuxt3 Nuxt-auth single-tenant configuration for Entra Id
Trying to setup @sidebase/nuxt-auth against our Entra ID for authentication. But keep getting the
AADSTS50194: Application 'app guid'(app name) is 
not configured as a multi-tenant application. Usage of the /common endpoint is not 
supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'. Use a tenant-specific 
endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant.

What is the correct setup for this configuration? This is what I'm using atm:
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from '#auth'
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";

const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()

export default NuxtAuthHandler({
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login'
    },
    secret: runtimeConfig.authSecret,
    providers: [
        AzureADProvider.default({
            clientId: runtimeConfig.public.azureAdClientId,
            clientSecret: runtimeConfig.AzureAdClientSecret,
            tenantId: runtimeConfig.public.AzureAdTenantId,
            authorization: {
                url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${runtimeConfig.public.azureAdTenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`,
                params: {
                    scope: "openid profile email",
                }
            },
            token: {
                url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${runtimeConfig.public.azureAdTenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`
            },
        }),        
    ],
})

This is how the auth settings in nuxt.config.ts looks like:
auth: {
    isEnabled: true,
    globalAppMiddleware: true,
    disableServerSideAuth: false,
    originEnvKey: 'NUXT_AUTH_ORIGIN',
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth',
    provider: {
      type: 'authjs',
      trustHost: false,
      defaultProvider: 'azure-ad',
      addDefaultCallbackUrl: true,
    },
    sessionRefresh: {
      enablePeriodically: true,
      enableOnWindowFocus: true,
    }
  },

Overview in Entra Id App registrations


Can you attach the screenshot of the overview page of the application in the Portal?

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74768053/is-not-supported-for-such-applications-created-after-10-15-2018-use-a-tenant

Added overview screenshot. But the urls are configured as in the referenced question

https://login.microsoftonline.com/${runtimeConfig.public.azureAdTenantId} what is the value of TenantID here?

it is the value of our tenant id, taken from the overview page, (Directory (tenant) ID

Then the configuration looks good are you passing the correct client id?

Yes I get the correct guid from the error message referencing the App registration in Entra ID. My current guess is that the nuxt-auth does not handle the autorization settings for the url so a bug has been raised in their repo.  the authorization setting is taken from next-auth which nuxt-auth wraps but unsure if that settings is honored in their implementation.

Can you attach the full project of yours

Sorry, unable to do that since this in an inhouse company application
